# Custom Meta Boxes and Fields Multicheck Issue

Tags: php, metabox

I'm using [Custom Meta Boxes and Fields](https://github.com/WebDevStudios/Custom-Metaboxes-and-Fields-for-WordPress) by Justin Sternberg and its pretty great, however there's been a [huge issue](https://github.com/WebDevStudios/Custom-Metaboxes-and-Fields-for-WordPress/issues/441) with using the multicheck checkbox options for me.

This is what the plugin's code returns:

```
'_cmb_seostats_multicheckbox' => 
    array (size=22)
      0 => string 'alexa_tr' (length=8)
      1 => string 'alexa_bl' (length=8)
      2 => string 'google_pr' (length=9)
      3 => string 'google_bl' (length=9)
      4 => string 'indexed_x' (length=9)
```

How do I test those checkbox options within an if statement?

Comment: This appears to be a basic [PHP array syntax](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php) issue.

Comment: You're a a basic PHP array syntax issue.

Comment: Hmmm... can't quit tell if that is an attempt at an insult or not. You might read the site's [behavior](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/help/behavior) section of the site's FAQ, just in case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the [in_array()](https://www.php.net/in_array) function, like so:

```php
if ( in_array( 'check2', $test_multicheckbox ) ) {
    echo 'Check Two is checked';
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I've been trying. It only returns true for my first position 'alexa_tr' all others return false.

Comment: This is how you would grab that data. But my issue was that get_post_meta had a true argument -> "If set to true then the function will return a single result, as a string. If false, or not set, then the function returns an array"